# PureCSS application to Jquery Datatables

Tags: datatables, yui-pure-css

Just wondering if anyone has seen or has a purecss (purecss.io) markup for Jquery Datatables?

I've had a look around and can't seem to find any.

Thanks!

Comment: I played around with purecss and datatables, i found that Bootstrap had alot more community and examples for datatables, including styling examples and extends methods by the creator

Comment: Thanks Jay Rizzi. Might have to come up with my own implementation of it.